# Typescript: prevent extra keys for a React prop object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When calling functions with object arguments, extra keys are forbidden:

```
function foo({ key }) {}

foo({ key: 1, key2: 2 });

Argument of type '{ key: number; key2: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: any; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'key2' does not exist in type '{ key: any; }'
```

However, with React functional components, this error doesn't trigger:

```
function Foo({
  obj: { key },
}) {}

<Foo obj={{ key: 1, key2: 2 }} />
```

Is there a way to make this an error?

Comment: Actually it does. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdBArgHb7AQtwBiEEAFAG86cOBABGAKwBccQXADWWAJ5wAvgBo6agJRyRouJRhMoXFkwA2l+moYAeXhDFSAvIPlLlsgIwbFKgBMsoHqanAA9AB8QA Which TS version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

When trying to use Foo as a component like in your example I get the error `'Foo' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.ts(2786)`.

After modifying Foo to return JSX like this

```
function Foo({ obj: { key } }) {
  return <div>{key}</div>;
}
```

The function throws the error you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript *should* be generating an error when you try to do that. The type inferences are pretty good. Maybe you have a problem with your eslint config? If you run the TypeScript compiler (not just eslint) does it generate any errors?

Well either way, a better way to type your function/React component props is to be more explicit, like this:

```
function Foo({
  obj: { key },
}: {
  obj: {
    key: number;
  }
}) {
  // etc.
}
```

or, a bit easier to digest for some people's tastes:

```
type FooProps = {
  obj: {
    key: number;
  }
}

function Foo({obj: {key}}: FooProps) {
  // etc
}
```

The basic pattern is `function MyComponent(props: MyPropsType) {}`